# Difference between Chi square test and Chi square test of independence

Tags: chi-squared

What is the difference between Chi square test and Chi square test of independence? Is there any difference or not? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Chi square test of independence lets you determine whether two or more random variables are associated in any way. It is not a measure of the degree of relationship between the attributes.It only tells us whether two or more random variables are significantly related or not, without reference to any assumptions concerning the form of relationship.Whereas,Chi square test is about whether two or more samples belong to same distribution/population.Test for independence involves a single sample from the population. On the other hand, chi square test tests involves 2 or more independent samples-one from each of the populations.

Comment: Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Please upvote if my answer is correct